# insert a entry into maindb during connection is on and open that entry name connection, nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i am having main database in which i am having a collection name 'mainDBS' and i am inserting a record in the mainDBSschema bt during the connection is on i wont get the record at the time when connection is on, i always have to restart the connection so that i can get the value ,  bt i don't have to restart the connections

```
 var mainDBSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        _id   : {type: ObjectId, default: null},
        url   : {type: String, default: 'localhost'},
        DBname: {type: String, default: ''},
        pass  : {type: String, default: ''},
        user  : {type: String, default: ''},
        port  : Number
    }, {collection: 'mainDBS'});
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question? It is kind of confusing.

Comment: i am trying to insert a entry into my collection,and then creating a connection of that entry name that i have inserted and trying to open that bt its not working

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are using to achieve this?